# Geometrical relationships

Tags: geometry

How to get this formula related to the figure, please?

[image]

$$d\vartheta = -\frac{dx \sin \vartheta}{R}$$

Comment: Welcome to SE! You'll have to make your question self-contained. You can include the figure and formula directly here (latex). Have you though of what would happen to does external urls 1 or 2 years from now ?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the question

Comment: OK, great. See answer below. Don't forget to Accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the arc length $L_R(\phi)$ subtended at an angle of $\phi$ radians at the center of a circle of radius $R$ is given by $L_R(\phi) = R\phi$. Now,  from your figure, one can read-off the following information:

> $L_R(-d\vartheta) = $ "opposite side of triangle with hypotenus $dx$ and base angle $\vartheta"\; = \sin(\vartheta) dx$.

Therefore, $-Rd\vartheta = \sin(\vartheta)dx$, and so $d\vartheta = -\dfrac{\sin(\vartheta)dx}{R}$.

Comment: Thank you very much